# Oracle SQL grand query does not recognize column selected in with clause

Tags: sql, oracle, with-clause

I have sub query as table using `with` clause, the weird thing is that if I remove condition `person_type.person.id = A.person_id` it works fine, so it will recognize `person_type.effective_start_date` and `person_type.effective_end_date` from `person_type` `with` clause, but not `person_id` as it says `person_type.person_id invalid identifier`, what's the issue here?

```
 with person_type as (
       SELECT pptt.user_person_type, paam.person_id, paam.effective_start_date,paam.effective_end_date
        FROM fusion.PER_PERSON_TYPES      ppt,
             fusion.PER_PERSON_TYPES_TL   pptt,
             fusion.per_all_assignments_m paam
       WHERE 1 = 1
         AND ppt.person_type_id = pptt.person_type_id
         AND pptt.language = USERENV('LANG')
         AND ppt.person_type_id = paam.person_type_id
         AND paam.assignment_type = 'E'
         AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE = 'Y'
         AND PAAM.Assignment_Status_Type = 'ACTIVE'
         AND paam.primary_assignment_flag = 'Y'

 )

SELECT .... 


FROM (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...) A,
person_type 

WHERE person_type.person.id = A.person_id
AND TRUNC(A.date_earned) BETWEEN person_type.effective_start_date AND person_type.effective_end_date
AND ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle is right, you've made a mistake.

```
with person_type as 
  (
   SELECT pptt.user_person_type, paam.person_id, ...
  )                                         ^
                                            |
WHERE person_type.person.id = A.person_id
                        ^
                        |
                see anything strange here?
```

Comment: yeah, i see baby :))))))